# Run Installer From PowerShell Shutdown Script

Tags: java, .net, powershell, active-directory, gpo

**Goal:**

- Run installers (.exe) on all domain computers at shutdown with PowerShell script.

**Given:**

- I'm successfully using other shutdown scripts assigned by GPO
- Script is actually running - verified by writing custom log files
- Installer is stored on network share

**Problem:**

- Installer doesn't start when called from shutdown script (below)
- Same problem with Java and .NET installers (both .exe)

**Already Tried**

- Script works when run manually
- Installer file share is accessible by "Everyone", "Anonymous", "Domain Computers"

#

```
$registry = Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -recurse |
Get-ItemProperty -name Version,Release -EA 0 |
Where { $_.PSChildName -match '^(?!S)\p{L}'} |
Select Version

$flag = $false

foreach ($version in $registry){
    if ($version.Version -like "4.5*"){
        "Found Version " + $version.Version
        $flag = $true
        break
    } else {

    }
}
if($flag){
    # .NET 4.5* is installed
} else {
    # install .NET 4.5.2
    & "\\ad1dc01\deployment$\Microsoft\DotNet\452\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" /q /norestart
}
```

Comment: The problem statement is big and bold... not sure what else I should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the installer is not finishing before the system completes shutting down.  Try the Start-Process cmdlet with the -Wait Parameter?

`Start-Process -FilePath "\\ad1dc01\deployment$\Microsoft\DotNet\452\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" -ArgumentList "/q /norestart" -Wait`

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  After making this change, my test computer is installing / reinstalling the .NET framework reliably.

Comment: I found this link as I was researching.  It details all the options for launching commands in PowerShell.  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx